# PowerShell and .NET delegates (Event Tracing for Windows)

Tags: c#, powershell, trace, etw

I'm trying to use krabsetw library (https://github.com/Microsoft/krabsetw) from a PowerShell script.
The script is able to create a session and configure it correctly, but failed to consume any events.

Script:

```
Function Parse-ETW()
{
    Param([O365.Security.ETW.IEventRecord] $record)
    Write-Host $record.Id
}

$Trace = New-Object -TypeName O365.Security.ETW.UserTrace -ArgumentList @("Session-$([System.Guid]::NewGuid())") 
$Provider = New-Object -TypeName O365.Security.ETW.Provider -ArgumentList @([System.Guid]::Parse("{1C95126E-7EEA-49A9-A3FE-A378B03DDB4D}"))
$Provider.Any = [O365.Security.ETW.Provider]::AllBitsSet

$Job = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Provider -EventName "OnEvent" -Action {Parse-ETW -record $EventArgs}

$Trace.Enable($Provider)
$Trace.Start()
```

I've also try "simple" form of Action:

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Provider -EventName "OnEvent" -Action {Write-Host "Event arrived"}
```

Also, no results.
Any ideas how to make it working ?

C# signature of the event consuming method:

```
public delegate void IEventRecordDelegate(IEventRecord record);
```

Working C# code

```
using System;
using O365.Security.ETW;

namespace ManagedExamples
{
    public static class DnsTrace
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var trace = new UserTrace();
            var dnsProvider = new Provider(Guid.Parse("{1C95126E-7EEA-49A9-A3FE-A378B03DDB4D}"));

            dnsProvider.Any = Provider.AllBitsSet;
            dnsProvider.OnEvent += (record) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Event " + record.Id + " (" + record.Name + ") received.");

            };
            trace.Enable(dnsProvider);
            trace.Start();
        }
    }
}
```